# Why is my Siamese network always predicting 1?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, image-classification

There is no change to loss and the accuracy stays the same.

```
left_input = Input((3,224,224))
right_input = Input((3,224,224))
encoded_l = encoder2(left_input)
encoded_r = encoder2(right_input)

# Getting the L1 Distance between the 2 encodings
L1_layer = L.Lambda(lambda tensor:K.abs(tensor[0] - tensor[1]))

L1_distance = L1_layer([encoded_l, encoded_r])
prediction = L.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(L1_distance)
siamese_net = Model(inputs=[left_input,right_input],outputs=prediction)
optimizer = Adam(0.0005, decay=2.5e-4)
siamese_net.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",optimizer=optimizer,metrics=['accuracy'])

siamese_net.fit([Xl_train.reshape((-1,3,224,224)),Xr_train.reshape((-1,3,224,224))], to_categorical(y_train),
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=50,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=([Xl_test.reshape((-1,3,224,224)),Xr_test.reshape((-1,3,224,224))],to_categorical(y_test)),
          shuffle=True)
```

I only have positive pairs set so I had to make the negative pairs set by using np.roll() on one set of members in the pair to produce a new combination. So it isn't predicting 1 because of the imbalance problem(since both positive and negative samples have the same number of pairs). I have tried shuffling the dataset, using softmax with 2 nodes in the final layer. I tried it on SVM with rbf kernel. While the accuracy was pretty bad, it was still at least predicting 0.
And here's the code for the encoder-

```
def encoder():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, (7, 7), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Convolution2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Convolution2D(16, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Convolution2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.build((None,3, 224, 224))

    #print(model.summary())
    return model

Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 218, 218)     18944     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 128, 218, 218)     0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 214, 214)      204864    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 64, 214, 214)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 64, 210, 210)      102464    
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 64, 210, 210)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 206, 206)      25616     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 206, 206)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 1, 202, 202)       401       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 40804)             0         
=================================================================
Total params: 352,289
Trainable params: 352,289
Non-trainable params: 0
```

EDIT 1- I added-
kernel_initializer='random_uniform',bias_initializer='zeros'

to all the layers so that it would stop predicting everything as 0. The training losses are decreasing now but the validation loss and accuracy aren't being changed.

Edit 2- Resolved it. It was an issue with my dataset.

Comment: I don't know whether this will solve your problem, but Dropout layers must not be used in between convolution layers.

Comment: Just as an idea/question: You have no pooling layers between conv layers and no dense layers towards the end of the network. Is this intended? Usually pooling and dense layers at the end are used...

Comment: I was just stuck on this for a long time so I replaced the original VGG network with this temporary one.  But VGG one had pooling and dense layers and that one didn't learn anything either.

Comment: Also you sample DOWN the filters. Often they are sampled UP in the conv layers. Maybe try to make a very easy network and see if it learns anything, expand later...? Here is some example you might know: https://towardsdatascience.com/one-shot-learning-with-siamese-networks-using-keras-17f34e75bb3d

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried to get the output of the layers and apparently the encoded input list is always [0,0...0]. I think this might be why it's always predicting 1. I don't know why I am getting [0,0,...0] though for "encoded_l=encoder2(left_input)"